# Android; How to return a method for value from an activity inside a fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

i am realy new in to the android so make a lot of mistakes. I am basicly following the tutorials. My problem is in the question but let me explain it anyways.

Basicly i have class which i use to store user details with shared preferences. And i am trying to get user details from it to show in a profile layout with a fragment. And before writing the user details to the profile fragment i chechk if the user is logged in.

But while checking if the user is logged, my app crashes, i think it is because i am not calling the method in the right way.

Here is the code with the problematic section shown ;

```
    public class userprofile extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment implements View.OnClickListener{
    View rootview;
    Button logoutbutton;
    EditText regusername, regpassword, regemail, regphonenumber, regbloodtype, regbirthday, regaddress;
    UserLocalStore userLocalStore;
    Context context;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.userprofile_layout,container,false);
        regusername = (EditText)rootview.findViewById(R.id.regusername);
        regpassword = (EditText)rootview.findViewById(R.id.regpassword);
        regemail = (EditText)rootview.findViewById(R.id.regemail);
        regphonenumber = (EditText)rootview.findViewById(R.id.regphonenumber);
        regbloodtype = (EditText)rootview.findViewById(R.id.regbloodtype);
        regbirthday = (EditText)rootview.findViewById(R.id.regbirthday);
        regaddress = (EditText)rootview.findViewById(R.id.regaddress);

        logoutbutton = (Button)rootview.findViewById(R.id.logoutbutton);
        logoutbutton.setOnClickListener(this);




        return rootview;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        if (authenticate()== true) //*(Crashes here)
        {
            displayUserDetails();
        }
        else{
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),loginscreen.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
    private void displayUserDetails()
    {
        User user = userLocalStore.getLoggedInUser();
        regusername.setText(user.username);
        regemail.setText(user.email);
        regphonenumber.setText(user.phonenumber);
        regbloodtype.setText(user.bloodtype);
        regaddress.setText(user.address);
    }

    private boolean authenticate()
    {
        return userLocalStore.getuserloogedin();// none of these seems to work
        startActivityForResult(userLocalStore.getLoggedInUser(),boolean);
        return ((UserLocalStore)getActivity()).getLoggedInUser();
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId())
        {
            case R.id.logoutbutton:


                userLocalStore.clearUserData();
                userLocalStore.setUserLoggedIn(false);
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), loginscreen.class);
                startActivity(intent);

                break;
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the shared preferences class that i use ;

```
public class UserLocalStore
{
    public static final String SP_NAME = "userdetails";
    SharedPreferences userLocalDatabase;

    public UserLocalStore(loginscreen context)
    {
        userLocalDatabase = context.getSharedPreferences(SP_NAME,0);
    }
    public void storeUserData(User user)
    {
        SharedPreferences.Editor spEditor = userLocalDatabase.edit();
        spEditor.putString("username",user.username);
        spEditor.putString("password",user.password);
        spEditor.putString("email",user.email);
        spEditor.putString("phonenumber",user.phonenumber);
        spEditor.putString("bloodtype",user.bloodtype);
        spEditor.putString("birthday",user.birthday);
        spEditor.putString("address",user.address);
        spEditor.commit();
    }

    public User getLoggedInUser()
    {
        String username = userLocalDatabase.getString("username","");
        String password = userLocalDatabase.getString("password","");
        String email = userLocalDatabase.getString("email","");
        String phonenumber = userLocalDatabase.getString("phonenumber","");
        String bloodtype = userLocalDatabase.getString("bloodtype","");
        String birthday = userLocalDatabase.getString("birthday","");
        String address = userLocalDatabase.getString("address","");

        User storeduser = new User(username,password,email,phonenumber,bloodtype,birthday,address);
        return storeduser;
    }

    public void setUserLoggedIn(boolean loggedIn)
    {
        SharedPreferences.Editor spEditor = userLocalDatabase.edit();
        spEditor.putBoolean("LoggedIn",loggedIn);
        spEditor.commit();
    }

    public boolean getuserloogedin()
    {
        if (userLocalDatabase.getBoolean("LoggedIn",false)!= true)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }

    }

    public void clearUserData()
    {
        SharedPreferences.Editor spEditor = userLocalDatabase.edit();
        spEditor.clear();
        spEditor.commit();

    }
}
```

So i still think the problem is how i call the method, what is the correct way of doing that ?

Edit: Here is the error section of the logcat ;

```
04-29 20:41:37.272  31883-31883/com.okanyakit.watchme E/IMGSRV﹕ :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 46
04-29 20:41:37.272  31883-31883/com.okanyakit.watchme E/IMGSRV﹕ :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 49
04-29 20:41:37.272  31883-31883/com.okanyakit.watchme E/IMGSRV﹕ :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 50
04-29 20:41:37.272  31883-31883/com.okanyakit.watchme E/IMGSRV﹕ :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 50
04-29 20:41:37.272  31883-31883/com.okanyakit.watchme E/IMGSRV﹕ :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 50
04-29 20:41:37.282  31883-31883/com.okanyakit.watchme E/IMGSRV﹕ :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 52
04-29 20:43:36.752  31883-31883/com.okanyakit.watchme E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.okanyakit.watchme, PID: 31883
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.okanyakit.watchme.userprofile.authenticate(userprofile.java:69)
            at com.okanyakit.watchme.userprofile.onStart(userprofile.java:48)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performStart(Fragment.java:1810)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:987)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1136)
            at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:739)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1499)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:456)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-29 20:48:37.142  32326-32326/com.okanyakit.watchme E/IMGSRV﹕ :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 46
04-29 20:48:37.152  32326-32326/com.okanyakit.watchme E/IMGSRV﹕ :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 49
04-29 20:48:37.152  32326-32326/com.okanyakit.watchme E/IMGSRV﹕ :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 50
04-29 20:48:37.152  32326-32326/com.okanyakit.watchme E/IMGSRV﹕ :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 50
04-29 20:48:37.152  32326-32326/com.okanyakit.watchme E/IMGSRV﹕ :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 50
04-29 20:48:37.152  32326-32326/com.okanyakit.watchme E/IMGSRV﹕ :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 52
```

Comment: post logcat, please. it seems `userLocalStore` is not have been initialized.

Comment: `userLocalStore` is null // mic drop

Comment: i can't initialize userLocalStore, in its constructor i asked for (loginscreen context) because i was using it in loginscreen to put user details in. So hat should i change it to ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your method you should say:

```
UserLocalStore userLocalStore = new UserLocalStore();
if(userLocalStore.getLoggedInUser()){
    //Logged in 
}else{
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), loginscreen.class);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
}
```

And `Override` method `onActivityResult`

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 1) {
         boolean isLoggedIn = data.getBooleanExtra("isLoggedIn");
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

And when user submit input info by clicking `Button` you check, save it and do some other stuff you want, if it is okay, run this code:

```
@Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    // anything you want
     Intent intent = new Intent();
     intent.putExtra("isLoggedIn", myMethodToGetInfoIsLoggedIn);
     setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
     finish();
  }
```

This is the proper way to check if user is logged in and if not - send him to log in.
Hope it helps.

Comment: i can initialize userLocalStore  when i write 

    Intent intent = new Intent(); it shows red and when i try to debug it, it said 
Error:(71, 41) error: constructor UserLocalStore in class UserLocalStore cannot be applied to given types;
required: loginscreen
found: no arguments
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Comment: in your class `UserLocalStore` you have constructor with parameter `(loginscreen ctx)` replace it to `(Context ctx)` and when you initialize `UserLocalStore` pass method `getActivity()` (it is a `Context`, actually).

Answer (score 1):

what i think you didnt initialize the userLocalStore and you are calling its function. but kindly post the logcat this will help to resolve your issue.